# Should I wedge a twisted fence post to reduce stress on the rail?

Tags: fence

I noticed in high winds that a rail had come loose from a post on my 6ft picket ("green treated" wooden) fence. As a temporary fix, I clamped the rail in place, and noticed that the post face was no longer in line with the rail, due to what would appear to be the post twisting.

I could attempt to force the face to match the rail, and screw and support it etc, but presumably the stress will make it forever brittle.

Should I attempt to wedge the gap?

I am wondering how it will return in drier months, and whether s wedge itself might be a weak point.

Comment: Some details would be great. Is this a wooden fence or vinyl? Are you saying that the post has twisted? This is common with pressure-treated wood, and you won't be able to twist it back. Even if you could, this wouldn't make the post "brittle". Please revise to fill us in.

Comment: Maybe a picture or two.

Comment: Much of today’s low cost materials are made from trees not much larger than the boards , as these dry they sometimes twist.

Comment: @EdBeal - Sometimes? My experience - almost always.

Comment: Yes much of the time unless kiln dried but I don’t know many that use KD for fencing.

Comment: I'll get a photo of I see it on daylight! Thanks for asking these questions.